# OS X LION: Support URL links in About text page

Tags: osx-lion

I am developing a Mac application, where i need to place About screen. In the About screen there are some text and url links(email support, websites) etc. to be provided. I don't know how to implement the view which accepts text as well as url and email links. I tried NsTextView, but it doesn't automatically taken care of this. I searched a lot, but couldn't find any solution.

Could someone please help me to resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocoa's built-in About panel will display a Credits file if it's present in your app's resources.  This can be Credits.html, Credits.rtf, or Credits.rtfd.  Either of those file formats support links.  If there are links in the file, they will appear as such and be clickable.  Does this not suffice?

Also, `NSTextView` should handle links.  It does not automatically interpret HTML strings, though.  Instead, you set its content from an `NSAttributedString` some part of which has the attribute `NSLinkAttributeName` applied.  You can set that up manually in code or you can construct an `NSAttributedString` from HTML or RTF using one of the `-initWithHTML:...`, `-initWithRTF:...`, or `-initWithRTFD:...` methods.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not using About screen menu. I added a button and which will launch a NSTextView or something like that, where i should have links and url texts. As you have suggested me, i think i need to play around NSTextView adding properties. Could you please give me some simple samples? So i can read and make them happen as per my requirement.

Comment: I think the terms I put in my answer should be sufficient.  If you look those up in the documentation, you'll find what you need, including examples.